# Wait for an API call to complete without using toPromise() rxjs operator

Tags: angular, typescript, api, rxjs

There are several APIs that I am consuming in my application. Although some API calls are interrelated. I want to make sure that the previous API call is completed. I am using the `.toPromise()` method to handle the scenario currently.

What other alternatives do you suggest **besides converting an Observable to a Promise?**

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert an Observable into a Promise at all.

You can trigger the execution of an Observable with the `submit` method and you can concatenate the execution of several Observable with the `concatMap` operator.

So, for instance, if you have 3 APIs which you want to execute one after the other and you need the result of the previous API to be used as parameter in the subsequent API, you can use some code like this

```
api_1() // returns an Observable
.pipe(
   concatMap(result_1 => {
     return api_2(result_1)  // api_2 returns an Observable
   }),
   concatMap(result_2 => {
     return api_3(result_2)  // api_2 returns an Observable
   }) 
)
.subscribe({  // subscribe triggers the execution
   next: result_3 => {// do something with result_3},
   error: err => {// handle the error condition},
   complete: () => {// do something, if you need, when the Observable completes}
})
```

The object passed to the `subscribe` method as parameter is the Observer.

You can read more details on how to use Observables with APIs in [this article](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a)